# Conevert HTML to image for REST api php

Tags: php, api, rest

I need to convert html div to .png image for my REST API written in php. I can't use ajax or JavaScript as i need to do it only server side. I don't know how to do it I have done some R&D on that but didn't get anything useful. I have tried htm2canvas & canvas2image its working when I run my code in browser but its not working in my REST API because its using JavaScript and ajax.

Comment: If you need to do it, go ahead and do it.

Comment: A div is build on client side so that makes it kinda impossible to process this server side before the page loads.

Comment: It makes no sense. A div is a html element, a png image is a png image. What do you mean convert one to another? Please give us an example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea there are quite a few examples why you want a div to be generated into a PNG image. Like graphs or personal divs for sharing. Still this has to be client side

Comment: I need to convert some html code(not entire webpage) to png file (like snapshot) and want to save that png file to my directory

Comment: How to do it client side?? I need to do it for REST API in php and API will be used for android application

Comment: Have a look at 'tcpdf' and convert the generated pdf to png with imagick, or search for 'wkhtmltopdf'

Comment: @BartScheffer so you reckon he wants to change the element on screen to an image? What does he want to send over REST API?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea the more I look at this post the less I understand any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this api for that in PHP:

https://github.com/blockspring/blockspring.php

And following is the code on how to use it.

```
include(APPPATH.'libraries/blockspring.php');

$image = Blockspring::runParsed("screenshot-webpage", array("url" => $source, 'width' => $width), array("api_key" => "br_3573_0608ffcd6b7845b5adc269aeabfe2212291ffc5a"))->params;
```

Comment: Blank transparent image is generated. What can I put in $source??

Comment: put ur url in source of which you want image

Comment: simply put your div in another link . and then put that url in source

Comment: what is your link of which you need image ?

Comment: I have string which contain html tags with inline css like this                               "<div id="html-content-holder" style="width: 100%;"><table style='width:100%; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'><tr>
    <td style='display:block!important; max-width:100%!important; margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */clear:both!important;' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><div style='padding:15px;max-width:100%;height:auto;margin:0 auto;display:block;background-color: #e2e7eb; '>"

Comment: First of all this code wont get snapshot for localhost the website should be a live website. Secondly I have uploaded the complete package here you can use this and change it as you like.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/eljjjj5701am75y/Snapshot_Code.rar

Comment: to sun it just open this url in wamp/xampp http://localhost/Snapshot%20Code/screen.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally Its working for me.